# How to persist form field data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using tab structure in UI. Whenever I click on a tab it loads fields for that particular tab id. There are total 7 tabs . Each tab is having different fields that are coming through database{http call} and displayed to view at the same time user clicks on it. I just want an object that can persist data even if I switch the tab. How to Implement it in angularjs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `localStorage` to persist the data even after `switching` the tabs or you can use `$stateProvider` which would change the states without reloading the entire view again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to persist data between states of you app.

Use the [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) to persist data when an user quit the app. (Look [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) for a better integration with AngularJS